# Converting functional php site to asp.NET

Tags: php, asp.net

I have had a php site for about 10 years now, and tweaked and tuned it over these years to finally knock it down to a page of common functions, and about 10 content pages.

However, I want to learn .NET. I have touched on .NET at work in the past, but have never dealt with anything as... specific?... as my site there.

...OK, I am babbling, sorry. Bottom line is:
Can/should I be using a function in asp.net where in php I would have a function:

```
<? DrawMapTable("id", "MapName", "Description.", "Filename", "Players", "MapSize", "Game") ?>
```

Which would draw a table, such as:

```
<h3> <a> $mapNameFull </a> </h3><img class='mapImage' src='images/$mapName.png' alt='$mapNameFull' /><p>$mapDescription</p><p><a href='maps/$fileMapName'>Download map: $mapNameFull</a></p>
<table class='mapTable'><tr><th class='mapTableCellBig'> Map Name </th><th class='mapTableCell'> Players </th><th class='mapTableCell'> Dimensions </th><th class='mapTableCell'> Version </th></tr><tr>
<td class='mapTableCellBig'> <a href='maps/$fileMapName'>$fileMapName</a> </td><td class='mapTableCell'> $mapPlayers </td><td class='mapTableCell'> $mapDims </td><td class='mapTableCell'> $mapVersion </td></tr></table>
```

And if so, how?

ATTEMPT AT A BETTER EXPLANATION:

For example, if I have this in my master codebehind page:

```
public String SectionBreak()
{
  string sHtml = "";
  sHtml += "  </td></tr>\n";
  sHtml += "  <tr><td class='mainCell'>\n";

  return sHtml;
}
```

1. How would I call it in, say, default.aspx
2. Is this a horrible thing to do?

Basically, I am trying to get away from using html in my content pages by obscuring it within functions that explain what the html is doing.

But the only way I can think to do this at the moment is to create a load of labels and have an onLoad for each of those labels, which would populate it with the code from, for example, SectionBreak().

Comment: I guess you'll have to rewrite the function in ASP. What is your question about exactly?

Comment: Sorry, I know I am not great at explaining... Basically, I want to know if writing an asp.net function that writes out html is a good thing to do, and if so, where the code would lie to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In classic ASP.NET you have server side controls which generate HTML fragments. For example when dealing with tables, you could use the [GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx) control.

Comment: Thanks, but I think I am explaining what I want *really* badly... :) Ill try to explain it better...

Comment: @FrostbiteXIII, you are asking whether writing a function that will output HTML is a good thing to do and as a matter of fact it is not. In ASP.NET you use controls that do this job. In ASP.NET MVC you could use Html helpers which represent extension methods and could output some small HTML fragments but the standard way in classic WebForms are server side controls.

Comment: Thanks for that @Darin Dimitrov, I suspected that might be the case. because of this, is it just not possible to do what I want, or is it still possible, just not ideal?

Comment: @FrostbiteXIII, of course that it is possible to do that. Simply write some function in the code behind of the page and have it return the desired HTML. Then you could invoke this function in the .aspx: `<%= MyFunction("param1", "param2") %>`.

Comment: Thanks again. As soon as I get my function call from master page working, Ill label this as the answer - sorry for the n00biness. :)